# Doob's martingale inequality. Does that imply $(2)$?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, proof-writing, expected-value, martingales

I quote *Jacod-Protter (2004)*:

> **Doob's First Martingale Inequality** Let $M=\left(M_n\right)_{n\ge0}$ be a martingale or a positive submartingale. Set $M^*_n=\sup_{j\le n}|M_j|$. Then
> $$\mathbb{P}\left(M_n^*\ge \alpha\right)\le\frac{\mathbb{E}\left\{|M_n|\right\}}{\alpha}\tag{1}$$

---

---

Does $(1)$ imply that for all $p\ge1$:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(M_n^*\ge \alpha\right)\le\frac{\mathbb{E}\left\{|M_n|^{\color{red}{p}}\right\}}{\alpha^{\color{red}{p}}}\tag{2}$$?

 If so, why? How could one show that for all $p\ge1$: $$(1)\implies (2)\hspace{1cm}\text{ for all }p\ge1$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality (2) you state
$$\mathbb{P}\left(M_n^*\ge \alpha^p\right)\le\frac{\mathbb{E}\left\{|M_n|^{\color{red}{p}}\right\}}{\alpha^{\color{red}{p}}}\tag{2}$$
is wrong for $\alpha\in (0,1)$ and $p>1$:
Consider    $M_n=\alpha^p$ for all $n$. Then the LHS of (2) is 1 and the RHS is $\alpha^p<1$. The correct form of (2) is
$$\mathbb{P}\left(M_n^*\ge \alpha\right)\le\frac{\mathbb{E}\left\{|M_n|^{\color{red}{p}}\right\}}{\alpha^{\color{red}{p}}}\tag{3}$$
and this follows from (1) since for $p>1$ the sequence $M_n^p$ is a submartingale by convexity of $x \to x^p$ and Jensen's inequality. Applying (1) to this sequence yields (3), since
$$\mathbb{P}\left(M_n^*\ge \alpha\right) =\mathbb{P}\left((M_n^p)^*\ge \alpha^p\right) . $$

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. Straight application of $(1)$ to $M_n^{\color{red}{p}}$ leads to $$\mathbb{P}\left(M_n^*\ge \alpha\right)\le\frac{\mathbb{E}\left\{|M_n|^{\color{red}{p}}\right\}}{\alpha}$$ Then, since $\frac{\mathbb{E}\left\{|M_n|^{\color{red}{p}}\right\}}{\alpha^{\color{red}{p}}}\le\frac{\mathbb{E}\left\{|M_n|^{\color{red}{p}}\right\}}{\alpha}$, it also holds that $$\mathbb{P}\left(M_n^*\ge \alpha\right)\le\frac{\mathbb{E}\left\{|M_n|^{\color{red}{p}}\right\}}{\alpha^{\color{red}{p}}}\tag{2}$$ Right? A last observation: in this case, in $(2)$, $M_n^*=\sup_{j\le n}|M_j|^p$, correct?

Comment: I added a line to my answer to make it clearer. Note that $\alpha$ could be smaller or greater than 1, so we should not be comparing $\alpha$ and $\alpha^p$. If this answers your question, there is a way to accept an answer.

Comment: Pardon. Shouldn't last equality in your answer be like:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(M_n^*\ge \alpha\right) =\mathbb{P}\left((M_n^*)^p\ge \alpha^p\right)\tag{1}.$$
rather than like:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(M_n^*\ge \alpha\right) =\mathbb{P}\left((M_n^p)^*\ge \alpha^p\right)\tag{2}$$? $$$$ 
In general, for the answer to my question, shouldn't it have sufficed to say that starting from a martingale $\left(M_t\right)_{t\geq0}$, one has that:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(M_n^*\ge \alpha\right)=\mathbb{P}\left((M_n^*)^p\ge (\alpha)^p\right)\le\frac{\mathbb{E}\left\{|M_n|^p\right\}}{\alpha^p}\tag{3}$$?

Comment: Note that  $(M_n*)^p=(|M_n|^p)*$. If $M_n$ takes negative values then you do not want to consider $M_n^p$.   Also, your inequality (3) is exactly my (2) together with the following line.